# undefined method sign_in for rspec

Tags: testing, rspec, request, capybara, specifications

I'm writing a simple controller test to ensure that we get a 200 status upon a GET request.  Every answer I've encountered online says to make sure we are including the correct `Devise` helper in `spec_helper.rb`, but nothing I've tried seems to have helped.

Error:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `sign_in' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApplicationFunnelController::Index::WhenAccessed "returns 200" (./spec/requests/application_funnel_controller_spec.rb:7)>
```

Controller test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe ApplicationFunnelController, type: :request do
  describe "index" do
    context "when accessed" do
      it "returns 200" do
        user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
        group = FactoryBot.create(:group, name: 'Testers')
        user.groups << group
        sign_in user

        get become_a_member_path

        expect(response.status).to eq 200
      end
    end
  end
end
```

spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require_relative "../config/environment"
require "rails/test_help"
require "database_cleaner"
require "rspec/rails"
require "capybara/rspec"
require "capybara/rails"
require "devise"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :view
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :routing
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :routing
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  DEFAULT_CLEANER_STRATEGY = :transaction

  def with_truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    yield
  ensure
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = DEFAULT_CLEANER_STRATEGY
  end

  config.include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers

  config.before :suite do
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = DEFAULT_CLEANER_STRATEGY
    unless ENV["SEED"] == "false"
      DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, except: %w(ar_internal_metadata schema_migrations))
    end
    Rails.application.load_tasks
  end

  config.before { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear }
end
```

Comment: Is `sign_in` a class method of `ApplicationFunnelController`? If not, what class or module does it belong to? Also, what is the value of `become_a_member_path`?

Comment: I believe `sign_in` is a Devise helper.  https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FControllers%2FSignInOut:sign_in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few search, and reading through the docs, I think a found an answer.

First of all, `type: :request` in a controller spec will not work as far as I know. There is a difference between [Controller Specs](https://rspec.info/features/6-0/rspec-rails/controller-specs/) & [Request Specs](https://rspec.info/features/6-0/rspec-rails/request-specs/request-spec/). I recommend you read the links provided so you can consider what type of test you want to include in your codebase.

Now, say you want to sign in a user factory in a Controller spec, what you can do is create a `ControllerMacros` module, and place it in `spec/support`:

```rb
# =================================
# spec/support/controller_macros.rb

module ControllerMacros
  def login_user(user)
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    sign_in user
  end
end

# ====================
# spec/rails_helper.rb

require_relative 'support/controller_macros'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # For Devise > 4.1.1
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
  # Use the following instead if you are on Devise <= 4.1.1
  # config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end

# ======================================================
# spec/controllers/application_funnel_controller_spec.rb

RSpec.describe ApplicationFunnelController do
  describe "index" do
    context "when accessed" do
      # You can optionally add this in you example.
      before do
        FactoryBot.create(:user).tap do |user|
          group = FactoryBot.create(:group, name: 'Testers')
          user.groups << group
          login_user user
        end
      end

      it "returns 200" do
        get become_a_member_path

        expect(response.status).to eq 200
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Loading the module this way:

```rb
config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
```

should allow you to use the `login_user` method in your controller specs.

If it comes to a point where this is annoying to repeat, you can optionally do this:

```rb
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

and simply call the method in your controller spec:

```rb
RSpec.describe ApplicationFunnelController do
  login_user

  # Tests here...
end
```

You can find more about testing Devise with Rspec in their repository wiki:

- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-(and-RSpec)#controller-specs